# #DJANGO - I need to display two (or more) rows of a table in my view, currently I can only display one of the rows

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

Hello people I am working with ticket creation and there is a 1-N relationship, (a ticket can have multiple messages)

I have a view that creates a ticket, in the creation process a message is added - All right here

I have a view that adds a new message to the ticket(s), thus 'activating' the 1-N - All right here

I have a ticket detail view view (code below) - Here starts my difficulty

```
def ticket_by_id(request, ticket_id, message_id):
    mesTicket = MessageTicket.objects.get(pk=message_id)
    ticket = Ticket.objects.get(pk=ticket_id)
    return render(request, 'support/ticket_by_id.html', {'ticket': ticket, 'messageticket': mesTicket})
```

the code view above works when the ticket has only one message, but how can I display the multiple messages in this view?

For example in the image below there is my database, highlighting two lines that are linked to ticket 9

[database, highlighted in ticket messages 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp2O1.png)

Below is an image of my ticket detail view

[my detail view of the ticket](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXMke.png)

How should I display in the view the two messages (or 3, or 4, anyway... more than one) that are related to the ticket, as I would show in my view (image 2) lines 9 and 12 (currently it is only displaying the first registered line linked to the ticket, in this case line 9 of the table) of the my table which are the ones that make up the 1-N with the ticket 9 (image 1)

***my html page:***

```
{% extends 'web/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Ticket #{{ticket.id}} {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<div class="ticket">
    <table class="styled-table">
        <h2> Ticket #{{ticket.id}}</h2>
        <style>
            td {
                padding: 15px;
            }
        </style>
        <br>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>ID: </td>
                <td>{{ticket.id}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Author: </td>
                <td>{{messageticket.author_id}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr >
                <td>Status: </td>
                <td>{{ticket.status}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Content: </td>
                <td>{{messageticket.content}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Created At: </td>
                <td>{{ticket.created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Show us the HTML in your view? The view code itself isn't relevant as the issue is with how you're rendering the data in the template.

Comment: @solarissmoke I added the code of my html page, but I think the problem is in the view because I added 
{
    aux = mesTicket.content
     print(aux)
} 
just to confirm the value that was being passed, because sometimes it could already get the two but it was showing only one of the values in the table, but not, it's getting just one of the values, the first...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, why does your message is not fetch with the id of your ticket, this would ease your work

Second to print multiple "messageticket" you should use something like:

```
          {% for t in messageticket %}
                <tr>
                    <td>Content: </td>
                    <td>{{ t.content }}</td>
                </tr>
          {% endfor %}
```

A loop is needed. As i don't know how messageTicket is done i can't really help you.

But if messageticket have a foreign_key to Ticket then you should be able to to acces it through ticket with ticket.messageticket_set (messageticket_set can be modified if "related_name=" is used in your foreign_key field)
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

and there you'll have all your messageticket

Hope it help =)

Comment: I understand how for is used I even used one on my page that displays basic data of all tickets, thanks for your attention but your idea didn't work for me because what I need is something like: if ticket.id is value in some line of messageticket.ticket_id_id a loop displays all the lines that contain the ticket_id (which is a PK), but I still couldn't get that thought from top to line of code, thanks for your attention!

Comment: In this case maybe you should redo your UML to ease your work. Good relation make your life easier